# Delete dimnames in R

Tags: r

with special software I created an matrix.txt file like this:

```
Motif name  AKB_CTCF-h1 AKO_CTCF-h1 AKZ_POLR2A1 AKZ_POLR2A2 
AKB_CTCF-h1 0.0 x   x   x   
AKO_CTCF-h1 0.40813213491755684 0.0 x   x   
AKZ_POLR2A1 0.9919703678068019  0.9936696431797781  0.0 x   
AKZ_POLR2A2 0.9911213889835596  0.9921991780345707  0.9782693635624957 0.0
```

I'm trying to create a DistanceMatrix with as.dist...
If I delete manually the first 2 strings in the matrix.txt("motif" "name") it works but I want to do with in R...
I want a squared matrice... I want to delete "motif" "name"...
I need help...

```
dm<- read.table(file= "C:matrix.txt",header=FALSE)
print(dm<-as.dist(dm,diag = TRUE))}
```

Comment: So does your file have a proper delimiter other than space? Did you really put a delimiter inside a column name? You really should change your file so that doesn't happen because that makes things awful to import. Are you sure there's not a tab there or something?

Comment: No that's the output...I can't change...isn't there any option to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
> dm.txt <- readLines("C:matrix.txt")
> dm.txt[1] <- gsub("Motif name", "", dm.txt[1])
> dm <- read.table(text=dm.txt, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> dm[dm=="x"] <- ""
> dm.mat <- as.dist(dm, diag=TRUE)
> dm.mat
            AKB_CTCF-h1 AKO_CTCF-h1 AKZ_POLR2A1 AKZ_POLR2A2
AKB_CTCF-h1   0.0000000      
AKO_CTCF-h1   0.4081321   0.0000000
AKZ_POLR2A1   0.9919704   0.9936696   0.0000000
AKZ_POLR2A2   0.9911214   0.9921992   0.9782694   0.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
# read in the text file
txt <- read.table(file="C:matrix.txt", 
  header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, na.strings="x")
txt

# create matrix of numbers
m <- as.matrix(txt[-1, -c(1, dim(txt)[2])])
m <- apply(m, 2, as.numeric)
# assign names to rows and columns
dimnames(m) <- list(txt[-1, 1], txt[1, -(1:2)])
m

# convert to distance matrix
dm <- as.dist(m, diag=TRUE)
dm
```